# Shorten C# ASP.NET URL's when submitting a form

Tags: c#, asp.net

My URL length is capped at 2084 characters and I have forms that need to have essay's emailed.  I am not using MVC, not sure if that matters. Forms are set to POST data, runat=server.  I just want the code behind the main page to load and send an email, I don't need all the variables passed in the URL.  Is this possible or does ASP.net just fill up the URL with VIEWSTATE data? If so, how can I send an email with this data without it going in the url?

Oh I also edited the web.config to allow a larger maxQueryStringLength but from what I am reading older browsers don't really support that anyway.

```
<form id="infoForm" runat="server" name="contactForm" method="POST" action="#">
  <!--Other form stuff here-->
         <asp:Button class="button" id="submitButton" Text="Submit" runat="server"
         onclick="submitButton_Click" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you need to pull email content between pages? Can't you just send it from same page on postback? Did I undersand you right?

Comment: I am a programmer who has come from PHP and Coldfusion into ASP so I could very well be doing it wrong.  My form is set up as follows and I have a function to run on submitButton_Click:        <form id="infoForm" runat="server" name="contactForm" method="POST" action="#"><asp:Button class="button" id="submitButton" Text="Submit" runat="server" 
                onclick="submitButton_Click" />

Comment: SOLVED:  By removing the runat=server tag from the FORM and disabling VIEWSTATE in the web.config it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending an email you don't need to send the data via the URL. You just send an e-mail using `System.Net.Mail` and your form data goes into the e-mail.

Code sample below:

```
protected void Btn_SendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage(
        txtFrom.Text, txtTo.Text, txtSubject.Text, txtBody.Text);

    SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("localhost");

    try
    {
       SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The email portion is working correctly.  It only fails with a large box of text added.  See my comment above, I may have the form and submit button set up incorrectly.

Comment: Your mixing up server side code with client side code. The onclick is client side code. Just use code behind to send the email. An asp.net webform only needs the id atribute and runat=server. It does not need name, or method. The code behind will handle everything.

Comment: Changed the code to <asp:Button class="button" id="submitButton" Text="Submit" runat="server" /> and changed the method from POST to GET and still have a very long URL with _VIEWSTATE data

Comment: I think you're confused. Onclick indicates the server event handler on a button control. onclientclick is the client-side handler.

Comment: Your form method should be set to POST. The data payload will be sent in the body of the request.

Comment: I changed it back.  I just moved to GET for testing.  Currently it is set as <form id="infoForm" runat=server name="contactForm" method="POST" action="#">  I still get a ton of VIEWSTATE data.  Tried removing the runat=server tag and modified the web.config with  <pages enableViewState="false" />  and still no-go.

Comment: SOLVED: I disabled VIEWSTATE in the web.config and removed the runat=server tag from the form.  Evidently if you have runat=server on the form it will append VIEWSTATE data even if it is disabled in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

The page is simply posted to the server, together with the viewstate data. You don't need to bother about URL's here.

Comment: It isn't intentional.  Not sure why the URL is being populated.

Answer (score 0):

If you POST, you can access that information using Request.Form["field_name"], then you can just collect all the information you need to send the email. Request.QueryString is used to retrieve information you sent using GET verb.

Comment: This is not necessary as I do not care anything about passing between pages, only from the main page to the code behind page.

Answer (score 0):

ViewState, POST form values and the like are not included in the URL; you needn't worry about increasing that.

Comment: For some reason they are for me a the moment. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly that is causing this behavior.

Comment: Did you change the method of the form to GET instead of the default, POST?

Comment: Just tried that for testing and still have a bunch of viewstate info